# Ruby on Rails - error when trying to render a devise login form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, haml

I have this haml file:

```
= content_for :page_title do
  = t :page_title_login
= content_for :primary_content do
  #login_box
    .span6
      #traditional-login
        %hgroup
          %h3= t :heading_account_login
        = render "devise/sessions/form"

    .span4

= content_for :before_closing_body_tag do
  configure_login_form(#{request.xhr?.to_s.downcase});
```

it is located in my `app/views/mobile/sessions/new.haml.html` path.

It gives this error:

```
Showing /Users/alexgenadinik/projects/cmply/cmply-app/app/views/devise/sessions/_form.html.haml where line #1 raised:

undefined local variable or method `resource' for #<#<Class:0x148213358>:0x14820dac0>
```

but when I comment out this line:

```
= render "devise/sessions/form"
```

it renders the page but without the actual form. So I think I need that line, I am just not sure how to add that line back in without getting the error.

Here is my controller:

```
class Mobile::SessionsController < ApplicationController
  def create
    redirect_to home

  end

  def new
    redirect_to home
  end
end
```

Any idea what I might be doing wrong?

Thanks!!

Comment: Note - before I started trying to create the sessions controller at least my login worked.  I just deleted my mobile/sessions/new.html.haml and at least I got an error that the create controller wasn't made.  Then I made the create controller, and now I got some new error, but at least it seems deleting the new.html.haml for mobile/sessions was a correct step.

Comment: can u post your controller as well as your _form file ?

Comment: @ArthurNeves Hi Arthur, I just posted my controller. Which _form file did you mean? I have mobile/regisrations/new.html.haml also - maybe that one?

Comment: Arthur means `app/views/devise/sessions/_form.html.haml`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

that form partial makes use of a local variable `resource` which it can not find.

You have to pass that variable along to the render call.

```
= render "devise/sessions/form", :locals => {:resource => resource}
```

You might also be missing other variables. My `new.html.haml` mentions also `resource_name` and `devise_mapping`. Maybe you have to pass those vars too.

Take a look at [rendering partials](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#using-partials) documentation.

BTW, your HAML should have `- content_for` not `= content_for`, because that is a control-call .

Comment: @Lass thanks..are you talking about the new.html.haml file which is under your devise directory? Or one outside of it that needs to make use of the devisee directory?

Comment: When I add back the app/views/mobile/sessions/new.html.haml I get this error in the browser: NameError in Mobile::SessionsController#new

undefined local variable or method `home' for #<Mobile::SessionsController:0x14916aae0>

Comment: Yes, the HAML comment was for the `app/views/mobile/sessions/new.haml.html`.
The _home_ error you get is because you have `recirect_to home` which seems to be incorrect. You probably meant something like `redirect_to home_path` if you have a route named _home_ in your `routes.rb` file. Though I have to admit that I don't quite understand what you are trying to accomplish. You seem to be describing multiple situations simultaneously.